# my C program keep crashing

Tags: c, crash

i have this little program where i need to replace whatever string i input with its place in alphabet so a = 01, b = 02, n = 14, 7 = 07... for example if i input ab36c as an output i should get 01 02 03 06 03

when i compiled this on another computer everything was working, now when i run it on my pc program crashes, i still get to input my string but when i press enter to get the result(output) it shows program.exe has stopped working. whats wrong here ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
//#define SIMBOLU_SKAITS 100

int main(){    
    char text[200];
    char *s2;
    char simboli[36]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
                     'u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    char morze[36][3]={"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13",
                 "14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26",
                 "00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09"};
    int i, j, garums;

    gets(text);

    garums=strlen(text);

    for (i=0;i<=garums;i++){ 
        for (j=0; j<=36;j++)
            if( text[i]==simboli[j]){
                strcat(s2,morze[j]);
                strcat(s2," ");

            break;
            }
    }

    puts(s2);

    scanf("%c");
}
```

Comment: Do you really format your code like this?

Comment: Don't forget to delete your pointer. It's a good practice and is also recommended. Not sure this is a solution to your problem, but you should fix that.

Comment: @AlexBarac: which pointer should he delete ?? He doesn't allocate anything in this program (BTW that's one of the sources of his problem.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I didn't notice he didn't do any allocation. Thanks for the comment, I'll be more careful reading the code next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do `strcat(s2,morze[j]);` but `s2`has never been initialized, therefore it points most likely to invalid memory, hence the crash.

**EDIT:**

... and `scanf("%c")` also crashes because you don't provide an argument. You need:

```
char c ;
scanf("%c", &c) ;
```

**EDIT2:**

This is the version without using `simboli` and `morze` arrays:

```
char *outp = s2 ;
for (i = 0; i <= garums; i++)
{
  char c = text[i] ;    
  if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
    outp += sprintf(outp, "%02d ", c - 'a' + 1) ;
  else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    outp += sprintf(outp, "%02d ", c - '0') ;
}
```

**EDIT3**

To summarize :

Replace: `char *s2 ;` with `char s2[200];` and replace `scanf("%c") ;` with `scanf("%c", &c) ;`

Comment: im a complete noob at this and i have no idea what youre talking about can you please explain in details or maybe tell me what i need to fix exactly

Comment: You need to initialize your pointer after you declare it : insert after `char* s2;`, `s2=new char[/*insert constant value here*/];`. After you output your final string on the screen, always delete the pointer : `delete s2;`

Comment: @user3446665: BTW your program is very inefficient and overly complicated. It can be done completely without the `simboli` and `morze` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It's the final "scanf". If you have an entry in the format string, you *must* pair it with a variable in which to put the input.

This is because any function with a variable number of parameters (like scanf) has no way of knowing how many parameters were actually passed. "scanf" simply assumes that any entry in the format corresponds to a parameter.

In your case, it detects an entry for a single character. It uses a "next parameter" function to get the address of the next parameter. But because there are no checks, the address it receives is garbage. The character is thus written to a random address.

This may or may not cause an immediate crash depending on how closely the memory is monitored (such as a 32bit processor versus a 64bit one). But I don't think I need to remind you that writing in random addresses is **bad**.

Replace "scanf" with something else or dump the value in a dummy (but real!) variable. *Don't use NULL, that won't work*.